# How to combine multiple individual eloquent models as one in Laravel and Eager load relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have many individual models and I want to combine them all to take advantage of eagerloading.

```
$match_query = "select * from feeds " .
                "WHERE (user_id IN ($users_size)) " .
                "OR (target_id IN ($slugs_size) AND feedable_type = 'review') " .
                "ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5;";

//Query works fine and return 2 results 
$results = DB::select($match_query, $consolidatedArray);

    //to convert returned php standard obj to array
    $results = json_decode(json_encode($results), True);

    $all = [];

    foreach($results as $result){
        $x = new \App\Feed($result);

        //I am able to get relation like this for single item
        // $x->user;

        $all[] =  $x;
    }

    //but this thing is not working (i am trying to eager load)
    $data = $all->with('user');
```

I get the following error

```
ErrorException in FeedsRepository.php line 67:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Why are you using the DB class? Why not use the required eloquent class, eg `SomeEloquentModel::with('user')->get();`

Comment: my query is too complicated. lemme add that in the code as well...

Comment: I don't see it to be that complicated... Anyway it does not work since you are calling the `with()` method on an array, not on the elements inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$all is an array. Array is not an object. So when you call $all->with(), you get an error "Trying to get property of non-object". Pretty straightforward :).

Your code seems to be needlessly convoluted. You query is not too hard to do in Eloquent and Query Builder. Read a bit of documentation and start using its awesome features instead of hacking your way around that :).

You code could be replaced with this much more readable snippet (or something like this):

```
$results = Feed::whereIn('user_id', $users_size)
            ->orWhere(function($q) use($slugs_size) {
                $q->whereIn('target_id', $slugs_size)->orWhere('feedable_type', 'review');
            })
            ->with('user')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

The important thing to remember here is that eloquent also packs all the power of query builder. In most cases it will be easier to read and maintain than full SQL queries.

Reading material:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

Comment: It works... just had to replace orWhere with where new feedable_type

Comment: correct @Eirtaza the orWhere in the closure should be a where for an 'and'.

Comment: well another question linking to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415347/eager-loading-only-few-relations-in-laravel-depending-upon-morphto